# AuthClient Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Ребята! Добрый вечер. Стал разбираться с yii2 и сразу же возникла необходимость авторизации через VK. Нашел решение от yii -- authclient. Проблема заключается в установки его. Composer не использую. Вручную добавил  компонент в yii\authclient и стал опираться на эту статью: http://www.satusoftware.com/yii2-framework-login-with-facebook/

Но ничего не вышло. Выдаёт эксепшен при добавлении виджета авторизации в view: "Class 'yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found", хотя он есть.

Подскажите как правильно это реализовать, какой мануал глянуть.

ps: в гугле ничего не нашел по этому компоненту

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что вы не используете `composer`, это означает только то, что вам придется делать все за него:

1) Распаковываем файлы в `vendor/yii/authclient`

2) В `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` добавляем

```
'yii\\authclient\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yii/authclient')
```

3) В `vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php` добавляем:

```
'yii/authclient' => array (
    'name' => 'yii/authclient',
    'alias' => array (
        '@yii/authclient' => $vendorDir . '/yii/authclient',
    ),
),
```

[Источник](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/kak-postavit-rasshchirenie-na-yii-2.0-bez-composer)

Не хотите? Используйте лучше `composer`, всего одна строка:

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-authclient
```

Что бы установить сам `composer`, в консоле:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

Для Windows можно использовать [Composer-Setup.exe.](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)

[Источник](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)

---

Все же не хотите `composer`, можете попробовать класс [Extensions](https://github.com/bookin/yii2-helpers/blob/master/Extensions.php)

1) Распаковываем файлы в `extensions/yii/authclient`

2) В конфигурационном файле, добавить:

```
'extensions'=>Extensions::add([
       'yii/authclient'=>[
           'name'=>'yii/authclient',
           'alias'=>
               '@yii/authclient'=>'@extensions/yii/authclient',
           ]
       ];
  ], dirname(__DIR__).'/extensions', dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php');
```

Измените пути к папке с вашими плагинами, и к файлу `extensions.php`, если это необходимо